# How do I use a formula written in one cell, in another cell (Google sheets)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have created a formula to get all sheet names (column A), with which a formula column has been created (column B), now how do I execute those exact formulas written in column B in column C?
The sheet[image]

Would highly appreciate it if someone has a solution to this or maybe a workaround.

What I tried:
INDIRECT won't work, I'll post the error it shows.

Error message[image]

Also, EVALUATE function is not available in google sheets.

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example.  I have two sheets 01/02 and 02/03.  In cell A2 of 01/02 the text "Hello".  In cell A2 of 02/03 the text "Good bye".  Now in Sheet1 I have in column A as Plain Text 01/02 and 02/03, the sheet names.  Then in column B a formula using `INDIRECT`.

[image]